# Python's multiprocessing SharedMemory ending in memory corruption

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.9, memory-corruption

I'm trying to pass a SharedMemory reference to an already running process using a queue. The problem is that once I receive (or get) the SharedMemory object on another process, the corresponding memory block does not seem to match at all, even the size is too big.

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


def f(q):
    shared_memory = q.get()
    print(f"In Process: {shared_memory=}")
    x = np.frombuffer(buffer=shared_memory.buf, dtype=np.float64)
    print(f"In Process: {x=}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp_array = np.arange(8)
    print(f"Main: {temp_array=}")
    smh = SharedMemory(create=True, size=temp_array.nbytes)
    print(f"Main: {smh=}")
    fix_array = np.frombuffer(buffer=smh.buf, dtype=temp_array.dtype)
    fix_array[:] = temp_array[:]
    print(f"Main: {fix_array=}")

    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=f, args=(queue,))
    proc.start()

    queue.put(smh)
```

If I run this code it spits out following output:

```
Main: temp_array=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Main: smh=SharedMemory('wnsm_2202c81b', size=32)
Main: fix_array=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In Process: shared_memory=SharedMemory('wnsm_2202c81b', size=4096)
In Process: x=array([0., (weird very small numbers and many many zeros...), 0.])
```

I expected to get the original `temp_array=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])` back

According to the docs, it is possible that the memory size does not match. Furthermore, I tested it with an array with 1e6 items, passing only the name of the SharedMemory and using a Pipe instead a Queue but still the same.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

(I'm on Windows 10 Build 19043, Python 3.9.6 64bit)

Comment: If you adjust the definition of `f` by `x = np.frombuffer(buffer=shared_memory.buf, dtype=np.int32)` you'll get your numbers back (that was the initial type). The change in size is most likely a rounding up to full page size multiples (her 4096) - but I don't really understand why this is happening.

Comment: @Timus You are right, I mismatched the dtypes :). But unfortunately because the size is being rounded up ([Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory)), the size of the array is affected as well . Luckily the items are correctly interpreted so the array just needs to be trimmed. I guess this is the intended behaviour so I am going to post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Timus

I think it is best if it is split into two problems to tackle:

**Problem 1,** Weird numbers:

> If you adjust the definition of f by x = np.frombuffer(buffer=shared_memory.buf, dtype=np.int32) you'll get your numbers back (that was the initial type).

The error was , as @Timus pointed out, a mismatch of data types:
`np.arange()` returns a `np.ndarray` with `dtype=np.int32` but I was trying to get an array with `dtype=np.float64`, hence the faulty result.

*Fix:*

@Timus' solution or to add `dtype=np.float64` as a parameter of `np.arange()` so that it reads:
`temp_array = np.arange(8, dtype=np.float)`

---

**Problem 2,** Too long arrays:

According to the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory), `SharedMemory.size` may be larger than originally. Therefore, the array's length may vary as well.

*Fix / Workaround:*

Trim the array to its original size, e.g. by using `numpy.resize()`. For that the original `shape` needs to be passed to `f()` as well. Although it is fine for me, following point might be a problem for others: Since `x` s only a view of the buffer, `np.ndarray.resize()` is unusable (it does not own its data). Using `numpy.resize()`, a copy will be made and **changes made to the resized copy wont be reflected in the main process**! To accommodate for that the values of `x_resized` could be copied back to `x`.

---

The fixed code now looks like this:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

import numpy as np

def f(q):
    shared_memory, shape = q.get()  # the shape is passed here
    x = np.frombuffer(buffer=shared_memory.buf, dtype=np.float64)  # dtype matches
    # x = np.trim_zeros(x, "b"), this doesn't work if there are zeros in the dataset
    x_resized = np.resize(x, new_shape=shape)  # changes not reflected on main process

    ###
    # make things to x_resized
    ###

    x[:8] = x_resized[:] # copy changes back to x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp_array = np.arange(8, dtype=np.float64) # dtype is correctly specified
    
    smh = SharedMemory(create=True, size=temp_array.nbytes)
    fix_array = np.frombuffer(buffer=smh.buf, dtype=temp_array.dtype)
    fix_array[:] = temp_array[:]

    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=f, args=(queue,))
    proc.start()

    queue.put((smh, temp_array.shape)) # passing the original shape
```

The weird thing is that while `x` in the second process is too long, back in the main process `fix_array` still keeps the correct size...

Comment: Regarding your last point: I saw that too and was pretty puzzled (still am).